# Why does my Swing application freeze a long time on JScrollPane.setViewportView?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, swingworker

I've built a somewhat absurdly large panel and want to display it. Unfortunately, when I run

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(absurdPanel);
```

it takes a rather absurdly long time to complete the operation. Any suggestions? I'm mostly concerned about this because I'd like the user to be able to set the panel size interactively, but also to be able to cancel the operation in the middle. The panel creation is all done reasonably properly by `SwingWorkers`, so the only major UI pause is on `setViewportView`.

#### Simple breaking example

This isn't exactly an extract of what I'm really doing, but it should get the general idea across. Note the extended pause between when it prints "foo" and when it prints "bar".

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Broken extends JScrollPane {
    JPanel foo;

    Broken() {
        super();
        foo = new JPanel();
        foo.setLayout(new BoxLayout(foo, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    }

    void ruin() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 200000; x++) {
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        foo.add(new JLabel("What is this nonsense?"));
                    }
                });
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                final Broken broken = new Broken();
                frame.setContentPane(broken);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void doInBackground() {
                        broken.ruin();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void done() {
                        System.out.print("foo");
                        broken.setViewportView(broken.foo);
                        System.out.print("bar");
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/632855/GUI/java/track-setViewPortView-JScrollPane-long.

Comment: `The panel creation is all done reasonably properly by SwingWorkers` - then I can't see any logical, real reason why caused by a.m. issue, problem is in code that you not showing here, be default no one from mentioned methods (in your queston) are used in custom code for JScrollPane

Comment: @camickr, I just posted one as requested.

Comment: what's inside setViewportView?

Comment: if you want to see difference to use setProcess()/ publish(), don't use doInBackground() for creating an Swing/AWT Objects, this method by default never notifyied EDT ans isn't designated for..., is simple bridge to Workers Thread

Comment: unrelated: don't extend a JScrollPane, instead use it

Comment: the setup looks a bit weird: what do you _really_ want to achieve by calling ruin from the background thread and let then let that method add tens of thousands of components (which is a lot, there might be alternatives like using a table/list f.i.) by switching back to the EDT and wait?

Comment: @kleopatra, the objective, perhaps not implemented properly, is to break up work done in the EDT to allow it to handle the window close button, resize events, and perhaps a "cancel" button.

Comment: hmm .. still don't quite understand your requirement: a) you have much work (configurationg of JComponents, f.i.) that must be done on the EDT b) while that work is done, it must not block the EDT (at least not perceptible), that is resize/cancel/some actions must be available c) the result of the heavy EDT load need not be shown while doing but only at the end?

Comment: @kleopatra, that's be nice....

Comment: @kleopatra, in the actual application I subclass `JScrollPane` because I want to handle resizing specially—specifically, I scroll the viewport as the scrollpane resizes so that it effectively resizes about the center rather than about the upper left corner. Subclassing the scrollpane lets me shove all that crud into its own class and out of sight.

Comment: deleted my answer - and back to step one: it's _really_ extremely unusual that the ui looks like the bottleneck, smells like something wrong in your setup. Anyway, same procedure as with all bottlenecks: profile, profile, profile. Good luck.

Comment: @kleopatra, I switched to installing the panel in the scrollpane first and then building it, and that made everything work. Magic. If I cared more about everything appearing at once, I'd probably do some crazy manual buffering, but I don't care nearly that much.

Comment: @kleopatra I have similiar case on one of my projects, creating the panel takes 1.5 seconds and calling scrollPane.setViewportView(panel); takes 13 seconds. (According to netbeans profiler). I did not use SwingWorkers.